# Change image and fadeIn on hover

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have the following code :

```
$('div.test').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'img/personale/test2.png');
}, function() {
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'img/personale/test.png');
});
```

How can i add a fadeIn effect while changing the image on hover?

Comment: Why are you setting the `src` to same image on mouse leave?

Comment: sorry my bad, firast is test2 :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein) and [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout) :

```js
$('div.test').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('img').hide().attr('src', 'http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/StackExchangeLogo1.png').fadeIn(2000);
}, function () {
    $(this).find('img').fadeOut(2000,function(){
      $(this).attr('src','http://londontechnologyweek.co.uk/assets/uploads/2014/06/Stack-Overflow-Logo.png').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

```css
.test{
    min-height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid;
}
.test img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
    <img src="http://londontechnologyweek.co.uk/assets/uploads/2014/06/Stack-Overflow-Logo.png"/>
</div>
```