# Adding a fade effect for onmouseover

Tags: javascript, transition, fade

I think there should be a simple solution to this, I just have no idea what it could be.

Here's my code:

```
<a href="/online-dating">
<img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d45e1ce4b0ed5a1e73808b/t/5c6faba9971a18628dc5bc4a/1550822313198/1a_online-dating%402x.jpg">

onmouseover="this.src='https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d45e1ce4b0ed5a1e73808b/t/5c6fabdeeb39313575ca52e2/1550822366487/1b_online-dating%402x.jpg'"

onmouseout="this.src='https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d45e1ce4b0ed5a1e73808b/t/5c6faba9971a18628dc5bc4a/1550822313198/1a_online-dating%402x.jpg'"></a>
```

the code works great!  I simply want to add a nice fade transition for when the mouseover happens.

Any ideas?

I have tried a CSS3 alternative, but the issue with that code is that it isn't responsive, as you have to define either height or width.  This solution is perfect given we can figure out this fade code.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change image and fadeIn on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324493/change-image-and-fadein-on-hover)

Comment: I tried to use the code from this comment above and it didn't work.  Oscar answered with a working solution below.  Although, I am still curious if there is a simple way to achieve this with javascript leaving the above (working, only without fade) code mostly intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div{
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d45e1ce4b0ed5a1e73808b/t/5c6faba9971a18628dc5bc4a/1550822313198/1a_online-dating%402x.jpg);
  background-color: #fff;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  transition: background-color .4s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .4s;
  -moz-transition: background-color .4s;
  -o-transition: background-color .4s;
  background-size: cover;
}

div:hover{
  background-color: red;
}

div img{
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d45e1ce4b0ed5a1e73808b/t/5c6faba9971a18628dc5bc4a/1550822313198/1a_online-dating%402x.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: this code worked perfectly.I only had to change the "background-color: red" to "background-image: url("your-image.jpg"); and also change the transitions from "background-color" to "background-image".  Works like a charm.  Thanks Oscar!  